# ember.js, how to set relationships in newly created records

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to set the relationship between two records, both newly created: I create `country`, I create `city`, then set that `country` `hasMany` `city` and conversely `city` `belongsTo` `country`. From the [ember "Models guide"](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/)

> you cannot assign a promise as a relationship [...] However, you can easily set the relationship after the promise has fulfilled:

```
var store = this.store;

var post = store.createRecord('post', {
  title: 'Rails is Omakase',
  body: 'Lorem ipsum'
});

store.find('user', 1).then(function(user) {
  post.set('author', user);
});
```

The above example doesn't exactly fit my case since I wouldn't know the `id` of the `user` record, which in the snippet is assumed to be `1`. My example is more like

```
App.Country = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  cities: DS.hasMany('city', {async: true})
});

App.City = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  country: DS.belongsTo('country', {async: true})
});
```

then, when manipulating records, I'd like to create and link all in one go:

```
var store = this.store;

var country = store.createRecord('country', {
    name: 'France'
});

var city = store.createRecord('city', {
    name: 'Paris'
});

// How to get the 'foo' created just above out of the store? What id?
store.find('city', ??).then(function(city) {
    country.set('cities', [city]);
});

// Same story, what's the id of the country I just created?
store.find('country', ??).then(function(country) {
    city.set('country', country);
});
```

question is: what to put in th `??`s in my snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i would implement it -

```
var store = this.store;


var onCountrySuccess = function(resolvedCountry){
resolvedCountry.get('id');
};

var onCountryFailure = function() {} ;

var onSuccessfulCityCreate = function(resolvedCity){
   store.createRecord('country', {
    name: 'France',
    cities : [resolvedCity]
 }.save().then(onCountrySuccess, onCountryFailure):

var onCityFailure = function(){ alert("Failed") });

var city = store.createRecord('city', {
    title: 'Paris'
}).save().then(onSuccessfulCityCreate, onCityFailure);
```

And If you had a set of Cities

```
var resolve = function(resolvedRecords) {
 store.createRecord('country', {
    name: 'France',
    cities : resolvedRecords
 }.save();
}:
var reject = function(){}; 

var citiesToSave = someCityContainingArray.map(function(city){
 return city.save();
});

Ember.RSVP.all(citiesToSave).then(resolve, reject);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I edited fixing a few typos.
Two problems with your code: (1) what if I don't want to save the records until I've finished setting up the associations? (2) In the end, the `country` field of the record `city` is not set, the last thing you do is retrieving the `id` of `country`. Presumably you wanted to go on fetching `country` from the store and sticking it into the `city`?

Comment: I set up [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/samemuxalugu/1) with your soluton. Ideally, at each click of the button a new France/Paris item should appear in the list, but...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/samemuxalugu/4/edit This is how we implement our hasManySavings . btw u had city : title (should've been name) And if i changed that and deleted hasMany relations (from model) it also started working(why? i dont know =D http://jsbin.com/samemuxalugu/6/edit Maybe u need to an adapter to save like this)

Comment: Hi @kristjan-reinhold, thanks for your reply. Your example at http://jsbin.com/samemuxalugu/4/edit works because you use `city` as a global variable, so it's created in the first callback of you promise chain and made available in the last. Look, I set up a repository on bbucket to explain what I mean:

[commit 7a1ba4](https://bitbucket.org/gghh/ember-relationships-snippet/commits/7a1ba4) is your original jsbin;
[commit 27679e](https://bitbucket.org/gghh/ember-relationships-snippet/commits/27679e) few adjustment to make it run.

Comment: [commit c21141](https://bitbucket.org/gghh/ember-relationships-snippet/commits/c21141) removed the whole association model, still works.
[commit 95afb6](https://bitbucket.org/gghh/ember-relationships-snippet/commits/95afb6), I remove the magic of the global variable, broken.
In the [Readme of the repo](https://bitbucket.org/gghh/ember-relationships-snippet/src/tip/README.md) I make a minimal example of what happens in your callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Ember Data cannot create unique ids. This is something you would need to do on your API endpoints, and therefore chain a few requests until you have all your relations setup and saved properly.

For example:

```
var country = store.createRecord('country', {
    name: 'France'
});

var city = store.createRecord('city', {
    name: 'Paris'
});

country.save().then(function (country) {

  city.set('country', country);
  return city.save();

}).then(function (city) {

  country.get('cities').addObject(city);
  return country.save();

}).then(function () {

  alert('all done.');

});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. (1) Whatever adapter you use, you'll get the unique ids created. I'm using [Fixture](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/) to play around, and it seems to do the trick. (2) you do: save country, stick country to city, save city, stick city to country, save country again. Which is, you hit the server with three `save()`, while I'd like to get away with two. (3) I invite you to go to [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zuxuqikaneyu/1/edit) which implements your solution, and click on "add data". Can you explain what happens? "Paris" blinks then disappears

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with the jsbin. I just tested the code against a simple REST endpoint, using the REST adapter instead of the Fixture adapter, and it works. 
(I also gave up on the Fixture Adapter for development because I kept running into issues like that and usually develop against simple local REST endpoints).

Comment: Depending on how much control you have over your API endpoints, you can get away with 2 saves, because you could just add a country foreign key in your city database object. Technically you don't need to store a list of all cities on the country object because you can just return them in a query. While editing on the client, the `country.get('cities').addObject(city)` should be enough to keep track of the relationship during your session.

Comment: That sounds like a clever remark but I am not sure I understand it. Are you saying that I should forget about the [relationships at the "ember" level](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-relationships) and manipulate foreign keys to link tables in javascript as I do in my underlying server-side database?

Now that I consider this option, I find it very reasonable and I ask myself what are the relationships for, I mean why emeber-data offers that abstraction.